# What is wrong with my CGI script to print MySQL data?

Tags: html, mysql, ruby, cgi

I want to display data from my MySQL database in a browser, using a Ruby CGI script.

The problem I have is displaying the data; It only displays the Title column, and for only one cell and nothing for the Price and ISBN columns.

I used "Title varchar, Price decimal(10,2), ISBN integer" to create the table.

I tried displaying Price and ISBN first but those two columns don't even print, but the data is in the database.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mysql2'
require 'cgi'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(
  :host => "localhost",
  :database => "tempdb",
  :username => "user",
  :password => "pass"
    )
results = client.query("SELECT * FROM mytable")

cgi = CGI.new

puts cgi.header

puts "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>ISBN</th>
  </tr>"

results.each do |row|

  puts "<tr>"
  puts "<td>" + row["Title"] + "</td>"
  puts "<td>" + row["Price"] + "</td>"
  puts "<td>" + row["ISBN"] + "</td>"
  puts "</tr>"

end

puts "</table>";
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this using CGI? 99.9% of what we do these days is using much more sophisticated technologies, such as [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), which makes it trivial to generate a web-page or a site. Also, accessing your data using the MySQL gem is much more painful than you need to do. Look at the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) gem, which works nicely with Sinatra. Between the two you could output the data in short-order.

Comment: I just needed something to display my own data, I didn't want to use anything fancy.  But, I definitely take a look at Sinatra and Sequel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with "#{row["Price"].to_f}".
Thanks!